# Shifting AC Signal for ADC

Tags: adc, programmable-gain-amplifier

I have AC signal that varies from 50mV (pk-pk) to 420mV (pk-pk). I am trying to use a PGA (programmable gain amplifier) to amplifiy the signal so that it can be sent to the ADC in an ATmega328P. The signal sent to the ADC needs to be within 0-3.3V. I can't add a DC shift centred around 1.65V before passing it through the PGA, as this will also amplify the DC shift, which puts the signal outside the ADC range. How can I go about shifting the signal and amplifiying it using a PGA which is supplied from a single supply?

Comment: I guess that your PGA didn't come with a datasheet or model number, otherwise you would surely have mentioned such an important detail.

Comment: I didn't include the PGA model number as the model I will use has not been decided yet. I was considering the MCP6S91.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't add a DC shift centred around 1.65V before passing it through the PGA, as this will also amplify the DC shift

Yes you can, and you *have* to. The PGA you want to use, [MCP6S91](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21908a.pdf), can *only* operate on positive signals, centered around a positive DC reference voltage. It has a dedicated V<sub>REF</sub> pin for this exact purpose.

There is even an example in the datasheet for a 2.5 volt DC bias:

[image]